# Accesing struct for use in weapons

Tags: c#, struct, unity-game-engine, inventory

this is my first post here so sorry if its a little bit confusing to read. I am also dyslexic so please excuse my writing.

So I am trying to make a top down rpg. I have created a struct to hold weapons and used an array so I can fill it out in the inspector

what I´d like to be able to do is to pass in the id variable from an inventory or something and then acces the other variables like damage and the game objects

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public struct Weapons {
    public string ID;
    public GameObject WeaponFront;
    public GameObject WeaponBack;
    public GameObject WeaponLeft;
    public GameObject WeaponRight;
    public float Damage;

}
public class WeaponHandler : MonoBehaviour {
    public Weapons[] Weapon;
}
```

so I´d like to access it like this

```
  hitobj.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC ("TakeDamage",PhotonTargets.All, /* damage from struct here */);
```

What would be the best way to do this? I am unsure what I´m actually doing as its the first time i´ve used structs

Player has 4 game objects as children these are the diferant states in the player for facing diferant directions each has weapon graphics under it so 4 game objects are needed like this in the struct  so taht i can activate the correct graphics

I was thinking of using enums 
to change between what weapon
to use to i could create an enum to
hold all of the differant weapons so 
that when i epuiped a weapon i can
acces the enum and ste the state to
that weapon and depending on what
state is chosen it picks the corrisponding 
id that is in the weapon handler

that is what im unsure how to do i dont know
how to acces the the id of weapon handeler

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 
See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Do NOT underestimate the meaning of punctuation within your posts.

Comment: Structs can be tricky to use and unless you really have to use them for performance reasons or because the API demands them you should consider using a class instead. In your case you create an array which is one use case for structs. However, the size of the struct exceeds the recommende maximum size of 16 bytes by a considerable margin. The size of the struct is 48 bytes on x86.

Comment: im gonna redo my question to try and explain it better

Comment: not sure this is any clearer. do the four weapons game objects have different damage?

Comment: I think martin is right, why are you using a struct instead of a class?

Comment: no the 4 weapon gameobjects are for the 4 differant veiws of the weapon they dont have any relevence to the damage they are just graphcis

Comment: i use a struct so that i can use the array of it so its easier to add weapons via unitys inspector

Comment: ok here is my question in more basic terms

Comment: i want to use an enum to with lots of differant weapon names then in the inspector i can just select one of the enum choicies say sword1  for example then in the weapon handler script it will set a string to the name of the enum i selected it will then access the array of structs and find the id linked to the struct then i will have acces to enable the game objects inside the struct as well as set the amount of damage to deal

Comment: i think to do this it would be easier to hardcode each weapon in and use a class but i still unsure how to check if the id set would match the enum chosen

Comment: so i could do something like if enum sate = sword1 get the values from copy of sword 1 and so on

Comment: ok after soaking up alot of information im gonna use instances of  a class like you guys sugested and just harcode all of the weapons all i need to know is how to acces theese variables to set like master variables or something

Comment: ok im now making weapons like this so all i need to know is how to check if that weapons id = something

Comment: ok im now using a class to do it and making weapons like this and assinging the values in the inspector......................................................................................................public Weapons sword = new Weapons();

Comment: ok if someone can post an answer doing what i did ill accept it then ill ask a  seperate question for my other problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really more about unity than structs, your stuct is just like a  class so you will need a list of actual weapons of type Weapon somewhere for your hit object to access the damage of the weapon it was hit by.

cant really say where without seeing all your code, possibly the bullet object which is hitting your hit object has the weapon id? you could have a global list of all weapons and then look up the one you want with linq

```
int id = hitobj.weaponId
float damage = globalWeapons.First(w=>w.id == id).Damage
```

Comment: im gonna redo my question to try and explain it better

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, I tought of using a Dictionary to hold weapons structs by Ids.

Here is an illustration:

```
        Dictionary<String, Weapons> weaponsDico = new Dictionary<string, Weapons>();
        // Load the weapons for the given ID
        Weapons rambosArsenal = new Weapons();
        rambosArsenal.ID = "RAMBO";
        rambosArsenal.WeaponBack = new GameObject();
        // ....
        weaponsDico.Add("RAMBO", rambosArsenal);

        Weapons terminatorArsenal = new Weapons();
        terminatorArsenal.ID = "TERMINATOR";
        terminatorArsenal.WeaponFront = new GameObject();

        weaponsDico.Add(terminatorArsenal.ID, terminatorArsenal);


        String targetID = ""; // Put here an ID from which you want to get the weapons
        // In your other code
        Weapons targetWeapons =  new Weapons();
        Boolean existsTargetWeapons = weaponsDico.TryGetValue(targetID, out targetWeapons);
        if (existsTargetWeapons)
        {
            hitobj.GetComponent<PhotonView>().RPC ("TakeDamage",PhotonTargets.All, targetWeapons.Damage);
        }
```

Instead of using TryGetValue you may also use extensions methods with lambda expression ad did @Ewan

Comment: im gonna redo my question to try and explain it better